# Initializing a Queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I have a class Queue that fully implements the Queue interface, however I have no idea on how to actually initialize the queue in my main Code.

```
Queue<T> q = ???
```

I have been searching the internet for the answer for 30+ minutes AND consulted the Java API docs, but I am outright stuck.  I know this is a simple question, and because of that its driving me insane.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Queue<T> q = new Queue <T> (allParametersGoHere);
```

Comment: "I have a class Queue that fully implements the Queue interface"

Comment: Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 4):

Queue is an interface. You can't instantiate an interface directly. Instead, choose an existing implementation. For example:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

or

```
Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

ArrayDeque is faster .

Answer (score 0):

`Queue<T> q = new Queue<T>();`